# How to stop debugging (or detach process) without stopping the process?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I often use VS 2008 to debug a .NET C# component of an application.  Sometimes, I want to quit debugging and continue running the application.  Stop Debugging kills the process I was debugging.

How can I achieve my aim?

This is not a web app, it's a local process that runs managed and unmanaged code.

I found the **"Detach All"** option in the Debug menu, however it is **disabled (grayed out)**.

Comment: Did you somehow accidentally remove the Detach All button?

Comment: Not sure it was ever there.  I did fined it, but it's not available while attached to my process.

Comment: I also have the same problem. No way to detach from the debugged process other than killing it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot detach a debugger from a process if you are debugging in mixed mode.

Make sure you are debugging either in managed or native mode while attaching to the process: either make sure "Enable native code debugging" or "Native Code" is unchecked in your project options, or start the program without debugging, choose "Attach to Process", and select only Managed or only Native.

Comment: This answers the question, but is a really poor debugging experience.
Is there a technical reason detach is broken in mixed mode?  Still broken in VS2022.

Answer (score 48):

Open the Processes window (Debug->Windows->Processes), right-click the process, select "Detach Process".

Answer (score 9):

Debug -> Detach All

Works great on my VS2008 and VS2010.