# detach one process from visual studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

My question is somewhat similar to this
["How to stop debugging (or detach process) without stopping the process?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671503/how-to-stop-debugging-or-detach-process-without-stopping-the-process)

but i want to detach from one process.

for instance, I have a windows form app which i also attach to a windows service. I want to detach from only service (detach all will remove debugging from all executions and hence i won't be able to debug other application).

P.S: If possible please mention for visual studio 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In the Processes window (Debug -> Windows -> Processes), right-click on the name of the process you want to detach, and on the shortcut menu, click Detach Process.

Comment: The right click didn't show any menu - is it because of some account settings ? or there is some configuration needed to get it.

Comment: @Umer Hm, it's strange. Anyway, try to see if you can do this via the Detach Process toolbar button in the Processes window.

Comment: In my case its not working. Terminate Process button is enabled. Could you help me in this regard

Comment: And what if I don't have any "Processes" option under Debug -> Windows ?

Comment: @Shaggydog Enabled functions depend on Visual Studio edition (Community, Professional...). My be it's your case.

Comment: @User1551892 Same here, but I think it's because the unhandled exception (in my case at least) at which the process stopped is terminating the process anyway, so something in VS decides that detaching doesn't make sense in the context.

Comment: The "Detach" option here is disabled and I don't know why https://i.imgur.com/Q45qMsm.png

Comment: Now I know why. I am debugging in Mixed mode https://stackoverflow.com/a/7563072/383779

Answer (score 14):

Just wanted to share that the shortcut key combo (in VS2013) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to bring up the Process window. The window will only pop up if there is at least one process attached.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Visual Studio Express**, there is **no Processes window** and I did not realized how to detach only one process.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you don't know how to detach in Express, or if you did figure out how, would you please tell us how.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing Mixed Mode debugging then neither the Debug > Detach All option nor detaching as mentioned in [Centro's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964765/365188) would work.

I see the Debug > Detach All option or Detach Process option in Debug > Windows > Processes dialog, when I am debugging in Native only or Managed only mode.

I have tested this on Visual Studio 2005 at least for now.

Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-detach-from-process-the-debugdetach-all-opt/225642